# google gson fromjson() TypeToken

Tags: java, json, gson

I am not able to understand `TypeToken` of Google's `GSON` api's `fromJson` method. Below code is very complex to understand for me...

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<ID_Name_Address> al = new ArrayList<ID_Name_Address>();
        al = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<ID_Name_Address>>(){}.getType());
```

What exactly is happening here : `new TypeToken<List<ID_Name_Address>>(){}.getType()`

is this a anonymous class? Throw some light on this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TypeToken` is a trick to obtain information about generics at runtime thanks to the fact that classes with fully specified generic superclasses make that data available through reflection.

The GSON user guide has a section on serializing/deserializing generics here: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types

To specifically answer your question, it creates an anonymous object that captures the generics of `TypeToken` in its superclass data. That data is then extracted through reflection and packaged as a `Type` instance with `getType()` to avoid memory leaks due to the aforementioned anonymous class.

Comment: the link that you have provided is usefull.