# Why are braces inserted in the code to call the getType method of TypeToken?

Tags: java, json, generics, reflection, syntax

Why are there braces `{}` in the following code

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ExampleItem>>() {}.getType();
```

If I understand correctly the normal Java syntax would be ClassName().MethodName(). Why are a space and the braces inserted between the class constructor and the getType method?

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005110/how-does-gson-typetoken-work) might be interesting.

Comment: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184226/google-gson-fromjson-typetoken) it appears that the space is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an anonymous subclass of TypeToken, which fixes the generic param to ArrayList. With this "trick", the Type of the generic param is compiled into the bytecode and not erased at compile time.